# GCD of large numbers of special form

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that $\gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1) = x^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$.

What is the gcd of $x^n+1$ and $x^m+1$?

I mean, is there any method to calculate it like the one I have mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euclidean algorithm works just as well. But if you want a formula.. First let me state a useful general theorem. The solution doesn't need the general theorem in its full strength but it helps to see the underlying structure in this kind of problems.

**Theorem**

For any monic polynomials $p,q$:

$p(t) = \prod \{ (t-r) : r \in R \}$ for some multiset $R$

$q(t) = \prod \{ (t-s) : s \in S \}$ for some multiset $S$

Let $D = R \cap S$  [the maximum multiset that is a subset of both $R$ and $S$]

Then $\gcd(p,q)(t) = \prod \{ (t-a) : a \in D \}$

**Solution**

$\gcd(x^m+1,x^n+1)$

$ = \prod \{ (x-r) : r^m+1=0 \wedge r^n+1=0 \}$ because the two polynomials have no repeated roots

$ = \prod \{ (x-e^{i2\pi t}) : t = \frac{2a+1}{2m} = \frac{2b+1}{2n} \text{ for some } a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

If $m,n$ have different powers of $2$ in their factorization:

$\frac{2a+1}{2m} \ne \frac{2b+1}{2n}$ for any integers $a,b$ and hence $\gcd(x^m+1,x^n+1) = 1$

If $m = 2^k c$ and $n = 2^k d$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and odd $c,d$:

Let $g = \gcd(c,d)$ and $c = eg$ and $d = fg$

$\gcd(x^m+1,x^n+1)$

$ = \prod \{ (x-e^{i2\pi t}) : 2^k t = \frac{(2a+1)f}{2efg} = \frac{(2b+1)e}{2efg} \text{ for some } a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$ = \prod \{ (x-e^{i2\pi t}) : 2^k t = \frac{(2a'+1)ef}{2efg} = \frac{(2b'+1)ef}{2efg} \text{ for some } a',b' \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ because:

$e | 2a+1$ and $f | 2b+1$

$e,f$ are odd

$ = \prod \{ (x-e^{i2\pi t}) : 2^k t = \frac{2j+1}{2g} \text{ for some } j \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$ = \prod \{ (x-e^{i2\pi t}) : t = \frac{2j+1}{2(2^kg)} \text{ for some } j \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$ = x^{2^kg}+1$

Comment: Thank you very much. $gcd(x^m+1,x^n+1) = 2$ when $m,n$ have different power of $2$.

Comment: @guest123456: No, by (my) definition the $\gcd$ of two polynomials is the unique monic polynomial that is a greatest common divisor of both. Without the "monic" requirement any constant multiple would also be a $\gcd$, and so $1$ and $2$ would be equally valid.